# UTF-8 saving in mysql not working properly

Tags: phpmyadmin

For some products (product_description) in my job website, I have set romanian chars.
Collation of MySQL tables are utf8_general_ci and it displays perfectly on the frontend of the site.

Problem starts when I try to save them. I tried from both MYSQL-Front, an app that connects to the database and with which you can work on the tables, and also with phpMyAdmin,
but no chance.

I tried exporting with UTF-8 and few ISO encodings but still I get funny chars.

How can I go about this and save my eastern europe chars right (so when say I get in trouble and need to import my .CSVs or .SQLs, the chars are saved back the right way.

thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Garbled_data and see if the information there helps.